# how does one force apache to flush HTTP headers on POST requests

Tags: apache, http

In my case I have an http client that works well when connecting directly with a Tomcat server that the clinet makes a POST request to the server and sends a large ammount of data as "chunked" html. Tomcat seems to flush the headers back to the client when the servlet responds to the request.

However in the case of an apache redirect, the desire is to get the headers without having to close the connection.  In ither words have apache respond after recieving just the request headers and send it's reply when ithas recieved the requests headers ( but not yet the data )

how does one do this or is it one of the you can't do that things :)